# WeatherKit (Swift) check if will be raining in current day and get only next hour forecast

Tags: swift, weatherkit

Playing with WeatherKit in Swiftui recently (very new to the language).
I'm working on a simple weather app and I'm trying to achieve two things:

- Know (true or false) if will be raining on the current day;
- Weather conditions (symbol name and temperature) for the next hour (just the hour next to the current).

I'm already displaying the conditions for the current weather.
Which is the best approach?

This is the function I'm using to get the current weather:

```
  func getWeather() async {
    do {
        weather = try await Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
            return try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: .init(latitude: 42.28851, longitude: 13.55401))  // Coordinates for SAN PIO just as example coordinates
        }.value
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

I'm getting the "next hour" condition symbol (and converting it into a corresponding emoji) with:

```
 var hourlyWeatherForecast: String {
    
    let nextHourWeather = weather?.hourlyForecast.forecast.first?.condition.emoji
    
    return nextHourWeather ?? "Waiting"
}
```

but struggling to check if rain (or drizzle, or thunderstorms, etc...) is expected for the current day.

Comment: This is just Swift — there isn’t any SwiftUI here.

Comment: This is part of a "manager. swift" file I'm using to get the conditions. The ContentView file is, as stated, in SwiftUI. Guess I should've expressed myself better. I should probably change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get `hourly` and `daily` forecast.
2. Get the forecast for today by extracting the information with

   ```
   daily.forecast.first{ Calendar.current.isDateInToday($0.date) }
   ```

and check if the `condition` is rainy.

3. If `true` get the forecast for the next hour by filtering the `hourly` forecast similar to 2. but comparing the `hour` component

**Edit:**

To get also `daily` and `hourly` forecast use the `including` parameter:

```
let (current, daily, hourly) = try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: .init(latitude: 42.28851, longitude: 13.55401), including: .current, .daily, .hourly)
```

You can check for you desired condition pretty simply. Inside the `WeatherCondition` extension add

```
var isRaining : Bool {
    switch self {
        case .rain, .drizzle, .thunderstorms: return true
        default: return false
    }
}
```

Add as many cases as you like in the `true` branch.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm having a hard time understanding how to correctly extract the hourly and daily forecast. I've updated my question with the function I'm using to get the current weather.

Comment: Managed to get the "next hour" condition symbol (original question updated) but struggling to check if some sort of rain (or drizzle, or thunderstorms, etc...) are expected for the current day.

Comment: Made it! Thank you Vadian! Going to give you credits in my app! ☺️ Learned a lot!